# Undefined class 'StorageUploadTask' FLUTTER

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLDQM.png)

I've been trying to figure out, why it isn't recognizing StorageUploadTask, with no luck.
I have installed the firesbase storage and core plugin.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post some code as text so we have a better idea on how to help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [UploadTask](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/UploadTask-class.html). The API has changed.

So instead of:

```dart
StorageUploadTask _task
```

you now have:

```dart
UploadTask _task
```